# Using Visual Regression Testing on Cordova app

Tags: javascript, cordova, selenium, regression

Is it at all possible to perform Visual Regression Test on a cordova built mobile app?

I would like to however I am struggling to find documentation on the topic.
Has anyone got experience with this can help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible. Your choice should depend on your programming language and if you're willing to use a paid service or not. There are free solutions to this like this https://github.com/Huddle/Resemble.js or using a command line tool like [imageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/compare.php), but personally I can recommend using [Applitools](https://applitools.com). You use it with Selenium or Appium webdriver and define a baseline, when something changes visually the test will break. For minor usage it's free...

Comment: hello thanks for your input, currently I'm using Appium with Mocha.js. I am actually a student using this for a project I am working on (I'm poor and cant warrant buying something) I will try out Resemble and report my success or failure

Comment: Glad to help. How many assertions do you have? With Applitools you get 25 visual validations per week in the free usage.

Comment: Im really confused, i can not get Applitools to work

Comment: By all means, add another question with your specific problem and details after verifying that this question doesn't exist already.

Comment: I wrote an article which saves baseline images at first run and after 1st run it will start to compare baseline with actual image and put the differences into "Differences" folder. Also, I add a code that hides changing parts and I put a reference link how to apply masking. Here is the link: http://www.swtestacademy.com/visual-testing-imagemagick-selenium/

Comment: and for mobile visual test automation with applitools, you can check this one. http://www.swtestacademy.com/automated-visual-testing-applitools/